# MySQL Cannot Connect Using Client

Tags: apache2, mysql, services

After removing, purging  and reinstalling MySQL due to a mis-install which got it stuck in a state where it would neither uninstall nor install, it is no longer accessible from MySQL clients but runs from the command line. Webmin seems able to access it and shows proper users and accesses but no desktop client will open it.

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 so what is happening?

Here is output from `sudo gedit /var/log/mysql/error.log`

```
2021-06-22T07:44:48.062446Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 291554
2021-06-22T07:44:48.103867Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:44:50.327015Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:44:50.671850Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:44:52.467963Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:44:52.468080Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:44:52.469742Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:44:52.470010Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:44:54.914425Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:44:55.310356Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 291618
2021-06-22T07:44:55.345470Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:44:57.356755Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:44:57.605602Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:44:58.789945Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:44:58.790057Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:44:58.791689Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:44:58.791984Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:45:01.559732Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:45:02.062880Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 291694
2021-06-22T07:45:02.093934Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:45:04.186594Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:45:04.513908Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:45:05.570748Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:45:05.570865Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:45:05.572489Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:45:05.572775Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:45:10.377502Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:45:10.811841Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 291748
2021-06-22T07:45:10.970688Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:45:16.668054Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:45:16.846861Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:45:18.013870Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:45:18.014014Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:45:18.015696Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:45:18.015983Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:45:20.203075Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:45:20.818028Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 291800
2021-06-22T07:45:20.851152Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:45:22.499637Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:45:22.680232Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:45:23.348625Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:45:23.348772Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:45:23.350479Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:45:23.350746Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:45:25.399967Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:45:25.815601Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 291852
2021-06-22T07:45:25.837932Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:45:27.284561Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:45:27.466144Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:45:28.107040Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:45:28.107180Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:45:28.108858Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:45:28.109127Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:45:30.019656Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:45:30.561833Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 291899
2021-06-22T07:45:30.569542Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:45:32.267715Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:45:32.446739Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:45:33.123870Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:45:33.124013Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:45:33.125802Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:45:33.126084Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:45:35.219833Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:45:35.810150Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 291945
2021-06-22T07:45:35.873000Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:45:37.400919Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:45:37.580442Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:45:38.324006Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:45:38.324153Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:45:38.325954Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:45:38.326241Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:45:39.923886Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:45:40.312430Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 291991
2021-06-22T07:45:40.331539Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:45:42.834104Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:45:43.038568Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:45:43.901389Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:45:43.901546Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:45:43.903467Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:45:43.903834Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:45:46.161612Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:45:46.566019Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 292038
2021-06-22T07:45:46.578421Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:45:49.842249Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:45:50.038745Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:45:50.801172Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:45:50.801304Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:45:50.802982Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:45:50.803249Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:45:52.480040Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:45:53.061492Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 292088
2021-06-22T07:45:53.075994Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:45:54.775560Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:45:54.996756Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:45:55.749758Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:45:55.749877Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:45:55.751639Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:45:55.751977Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:45:57.933969Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:45:58.561936Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 292134
2021-06-22T07:45:58.572865Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:46:00.142032Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:46:00.309393Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:46:01.209361Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:46:01.209498Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:46:01.211105Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:46:01.211371Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:46:03.624477Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:46:04.061190Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 292194
2021-06-22T07:46:04.076725Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:46:05.716946Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:46:05.972036Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:46:06.716768Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:46:06.716880Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:46:06.718563Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:46:06.718867Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:46:08.754032Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:46:09.311783Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 292241
2021-06-22T07:46:09.338943Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:46:10.775141Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:46:10.988432Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:46:11.675056Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:46:11.675188Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:46:11.676924Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:46:11.677199Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:46:13.404443Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:46:13.810940Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 292288
2021-06-22T07:46:13.830057Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:46:16.041630Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:46:16.255643Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:46:17.099856Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:46:17.099992Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:46:17.101651Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:46:17.101917Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:46:19.382363Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:46:19.817796Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 292334
2021-06-22T07:46:20.233528Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:46:21.983248Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:46:22.302157Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:46:22.951200Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:46:22.951333Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:46:22.953053Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:46:22.953321Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:46:25.980857Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:46:26.562619Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 292390
2021-06-22T07:46:26.760604Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:46:28.333043Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:46:28.555343Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:46:29.351684Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:46:29.351815Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:46:29.353429Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000068] [Server] unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'.
2021-06-22T07:46:29.353731Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-06-22T07:46:31.431986Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:46:32.064693Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 292436
2021-06-22T07:46:32.121739Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:46:33.541176Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:46:33.713428Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:46:34.352432Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:46:34.352606Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:46:34.359100Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:46:48.204594Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1).
2021-06-22T07:46:49.387674Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
2021-06-22T07:46:49.659643Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1) starting as process 292503
2021-06-22T07:46:49.665377Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-06-22T07:46:50.440921Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-06-22T07:46:50.558374Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2021-06-22T07:46:50.863153Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2021-06-22T07:46:50.863276Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2021-06-22T07:46:50.869333Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu).
```

Seeing `unknown option '--bind-address 0.0.0.0'` I remarked out the line in `/etc/mysql/my.conf` and MySQL's service now restarts but still will not open in any client.

Not sure if it's related but I noticed that Apache2 isn't running either so here is additional output:

```
sudo journalctl -xe
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

An ExecStart= process belonging to unit apache2.service has exited.

The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Jun 22 10:54:26 ubuntu-studio systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result '>
Subject: Unit failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

The unit apache2.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-co>
Jun 22 10:54:26 ubuntu-studio systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Serve>
Subject: A start job for unit apache2.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd
Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

A start job for unit apache2.service has finished with a failure.

The job identifier is 2820 and the job result is failed.
Jun 22 10:54:26 ubuntu-studio sudo[5542]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session close>
Jun 22 10:55:01 ubuntu-studio sudo[5575]:      don : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/don >
Jun 22 10:55:01 ubuntu-studio sudo[5575]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opene>
lines 3045-3067/3067 (END)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the contents of `/var/log/mysql/error.log`? This will make it much easier to diagnose and suggest specific solutions 

Comment: Added the requested output.

Comment: There are a couple of things that stand out here. One is the "Ubuntu Studio" bit in the Apache log. I don't know whether that distro does anything weird with a LAMP stack, as I've never used it. Your `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf` file is probably misconfigured based on the `bind-address` issue and the resulting "Port 0" bit. Apache looks like it's running either as a regular user, or its home directory has been set to your home directory without having permission to read or write from there. This can be resolved with some modifications to AppArmor. Can you confirm the Ubuntu Studio bit?

Comment: No, Ubuntu Studio does not do anything “weird” and simply pre-installs multimedia and graphics apps that must be installed individually in the non-Studio version.